# NODE JS cancel request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using this code to download files in node js :

```
var currentVideoRequest = null;

window.spawnVideoPlayer = function (url, subs, movieModel,tag) {
    if(currentVideoRequest) {
    try
    {
      currentVideoRequest.abort();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      alert(err.message);
    }

    }

    var fs = require('fs');
    var urlrequest = currentVideoRequest = require('request');

    urlrequest.get({url: url, encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, response, body) {
      fs.writeFile(FILEURL, body, 'binary', function(err) {

      }); 
    });
}
```

And in the `currentVideoRequest.abort();` i get this error:

```
    Object function request(uri, options, callback) {
  if (typeof uri === 'undefined') throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
  if ((typeof options === 'function') && !callback) callback = options
  if (options && typeof options === 'object') {
    options.uri = uri
  } else if (typeof uri === 'string') {
    options = {uri:uri}
  } else {
    options = uri
  }

  options = copy(options)

  if (callback) options.callback = callback
  var r = new Request(options)
  return r
} has no method 'abort'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to @Etai's answer, you need to require the request module before using it for one instance of the request. Something like this:

```
var request = require('request');
// ...
// then later in the code
var urlrequest = request.get(uri, function(err, response, body) {
    // process data here
});

// later, you'd abort this as:
urlrequest.abort();
```

Note that I'm saving the instance with `var urlrequest = request.get(params, callback);` so that I can call abort on it later.

Answer (score 3):

your currentVideoRequest is a constructor for a request object, not a request object, which is why this is failing.

The request constructor returns a request object when invoked, i.e.

```
require('request')('uri', function(err, resp, body){})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use abort() method to stop that request.

```
var reqObj = request({uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'  }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('API requested ') ;
    if (!err){
        console.log(body);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

reqObj.abort();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this method to get what you need.
I used async in this way, which makes both the code cleaner and less callback .

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        let urlRequest = await customRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/search?title=foo");
        urlRequest.abort();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();

function customRequest(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(url, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            if (res.statusCode !== 200)
                reject("my Error ");

            resolve(res);
        })
    })
}
```

Also, if you do not need to answer the urlRequest variable,you can remove the await from the function as shown below.

```
try {
        let urlRequest =  customRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/search?title="); // run in background !
        urlRequest.abort();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Finally, since our request returns an exception if you make a mistake, you can write abort() in the catch block if needed.

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        var urlRequest =await  customRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/search?title=");
    } catch (e) {
        urlRequest.abort();
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Also, because the `customRequest()`  function returns a promise note, you use  `then()`  instead of async await.